# Deleting Derived Data from Xcode 4.2 project doesn't re-index project

Tags: xcode, autocomplete, xcode4.2

Indexing, code completion, & coloring disappear from my projects on a fairly regular basis, usually right after I add a file.  And then it returns hours or days later, usually for unknown reasons (I've tried keeping a record but it's pretty random).  CMD-clicking on even known terms (like viewDidLoad: or NSLocalizedString) result in a "Symbol Not Found" error.

It happens with Xcode 4.2 (I believe it happened in Xcode 4.0.2, but not as frequent).
I have no build errors, warnings, or static analysis messages.
I've restarted Xcode.
I've tried turning precompile off.
I don't have a case where I've got a circular header file include/import.
It happens if I use gcc, LLVM, CLang (in whatever combo).
It happens if I use iOS 4.3 or 5.0.
I've tried deleting the "derived data.", and even only the Index/ path.
After deletion & re-build I see the .hmap file & .xcindex folder (filled with db.xcodeindexdb* files).

...but I can't get code-completion, symbol detection, or coloring back.

What else can I do?  I sincerely appreciate the help.

Comment: No idea, but I have the same problem that comes and goes. Had it in Xcode 3, too. Really frustrating. It's all working one day, then it'll stop. And you're right, sometimes it'll suddenly start working again. Wish I understood it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most reliable way I've found to force re-indexing of the project is to change the build settings, specifically 'Run Static Analyzer' - I wish I had a real answer though.

Comment: Strange, but this worked for me too. Xcode 5.0.2, Mac OS 10.9.1. I changed the build setting "Analyze During 'Build'" to Yes and build the project – and hey, presto – everything was reindexed. (I changed the setting back to No and everything still worked.)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried a clean install (sudo /Developer/Library/uninstall-devtools)?

Comment: no, what is that supposed to do?  clear the caches?  I can't do that w/o re-installing?

Answer (score 1):

I have exactly the same problem for one particular project. Following workaround works for me: apart from deleting Derived Data , I make an SVN update or revert any file of the project.    If the project file itself is changed  my Xcode displays wrong target ,so I close the project and re-open it and then indexing starts properly.

Answer (score 0):

This might seem like a silly response, but have you tried to repair file permissions under disk maintenance?

Comment: yeah.  I had to do that after upgrading to Lion.

Comment: And I just did it again... no effect.

Answer (score 0):

Your thread is old, but anyway...

Deleting the derived data folder helps me everytime. I have to do it quite regularly, which is very annoying. Your find the path in the xCode-Settings(cmd+,) in the locations-tab.

Comment: The best I get is toggling settings in the Project.  Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 0):

I just had this issue. What worked for me is clearing the derived data, then closing the project and re-opening it. It didn't reindex until I closed and re-opened the project. The project never compiled fully, so it didn't even have to finish building to work.